# Is the children's story, A Christmas Carol also a fairy tale?

Tags: word-meaning

I wonder whether ***A Christmas Carol*** is a fairy tale or not.

I looked up the word in Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary and
the entry for fairy tale reads ***a story about magic or fairies***.
As there are ghosts but no magics or fairies in the story,
I think *A Christmas Carol* can not be a fairy tale but I am not sure.

May I ask you to explain about this and answer what is right?

Comment: I fixed the title of the story - I don't know if it gets translated differently in your language, but the title is **A** Christmas Carol, not "The".

Comment: A Christmas Carol isn't really a children's story.  It's suitable for them, but it is a morality tale that was intended for an adult audience when it was published.

Comment: @JasonPatterson I didn't know it was initially for adults, but as now I am thinking about it, it makes sense pretty well. Thank you. Then, how about it being a fairy tale or not?

Comment: @SmartHumanism - It's a _novel_ (which was originally published in serial form) and it can no more be called a "fairy tale" than can _Catch 22_ or _À la recherche du temps perdu._

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about interpretation of literature, and not about learning English specifically.

Comment: @user3169: ... and e.g. J.R.R. Tolkien would doubtless have strong opinions on the matter.

Comment: @user3169 - I can see that, but IMO this question is also about how English is actually used in practical speaking - e.g., what we actually call a fairy tale in practice.

Comment: @stangdon Anyway the OP actually came to the correct conclusion at least based on the given definition. It is OK to ask if the premise is correct or not, but some justification for that needs to be added to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is somewhat a matter of opinion, but I would say **no, *A Christmas Carol* is not a fairy tale.**

A [*fairy tale*](http://teacher.scholastic.com/writewit/mff/fairytales_discovering.htm) is usually defined as a simple story for children which involves mythical creatures; they also usually do not have just one author or version, but are passed on as folk stories.  Typical examples might be [Rumplestiltskin](http://www.pitt.edu/~dash/grimm055.html), or [Jack and the Beanstalk](http://www.pitt.edu/~dash/type0328jack.html).  *A Christmas Carol*  involves ghosts, but has one specific version by one specific author, is not intended specifically for children, is not particularly short, and contains thematic elements, like social commentary, which are not usually part of fairy tales.

Comment: A matter of opinion - yep. Fairy tale is a broad term, shading into metaphor,  dependant on context. 'Wasn't me who broke that window' could be described as a fairy tale. . .